# How to change the password for my Apple ID from my iPad?

Tags: ipad, apple-id, password

I want to change the password of my iPad, I mean the one that I need to type when installing software.

How do I do it? I looked everywhere in the Settings app for a "Change password" entry, but couldn't find an option for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to App Store or iTunes Store and scroll to the bottom, then pick your Apple ID. Select View Apple ID and log in with your current password. Pick Apple ID at the top and change your password, then press Done.